# Refresh or Create Materialized view? Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, materialized-views

I have a materialized view that sometimes gets erased when our data pipeline does a full refresh. Is there a way to include some logic in the query to refresh if it exists, and if not, then create it?

Something like this

```
refresh materialized view my_mat_view

if my_mat_view does not exist then execute the code below

create materialized view my_mat_view as select * from table
```

Comment: "sometimes gets erased".  That sounds like a problem that should be fixed.

Comment: Yes I agree, this is a temporary fix while we reorganize the pipeline

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to use a `create .. if not exists` with the no data option, and then run the `refresh` unconditionally:

```
create materialized view if not exists my_mat_view 
as 
select * 
from table
with no data; --<< don't populate the data just yet

-- the mview will exists now, no matter what
refresh materialized view my_mat_view;
```